# Clear MapView layer in ArcGIS Runtime for Android

Tags: android, arcgis, esri, arcgis-runtime

In my project, I use a `MapView` from ArcGIS Runtime for Android. I perform a query for features within a polygon and with a certain attribute value. When the search completes, I want to clear all existing graphics on the map. I tried `map.removeAll()` but it clears all of my layers! How can I clear all graphics instead of removing all layers?

This is my code:

```
private class AsyncQueryTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, FeatureResult> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progress = new ProgressDialog(Naghshe.this);
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(Naghshe.this, "",
                "Please wait....query task is executing");

    }


    @Override
    protected FeatureResult doInBackground(String... queryArray) {

        if (queryArray == null || queryArray.length <= 1)
            return null;

        String url = queryArray[0];
        QueryParameters qParameters = new QueryParameters();
        String whereClause = queryArray[1];
       // SpatialReference sr = SpatialReference.create(102100);
        qParameters.setGeometry(map.getExtent());
      //  qParameters.setOutSpatialReference(sr);
        qParameters.setReturnGeometry(true);
        qParameters.setWhere(whereClause);

        QueryTask qTask = new QueryTask(url);

        try {
            FeatureResult results = qTask.execute(qParameters);

            return results;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(FeatureResult results) {


        if (results != null) {
            int size = (int) results.featureCount();

            for (Object element : results) {
                progress.incrementProgressBy(size / 100);
                if (element instanceof Feature) {
                    Feature feature = (Feature) element;
                    Graphic graphic = new Graphic(feature.getGeometry(),
                            feature.getSymbol(), feature.getAttributes());

                    _graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
                    _graphicsLayer.addGraphic(graphic);

                    SimpleRenderer sr = new SimpleRenderer(new SimpleFillSymbol(Color.RED));
                    _graphicsLayer.setRenderer(sr);

                    boolean m =false;
                    if(!m)
                    {
                        map.addLayer(_graphicsLayer);
                        m=true;
                    }else {
                        map.removeLayer(_graphicsLayer);

                        map.addLayer(_graphicsLayer);
                    }

                    map.zoomin();

                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
        progress.dismiss();
        boolQuery = false;
    }
```

Comment: FYI it looks like you're creating a new `GraphicsLayer` for every search result. You should probably create your `GraphicsLayer` outside of the loop so that you have multiple graphics in one layer instead of multiple layers with one graphic each. But that's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MapView.removeAll()`](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/MapView.html#removeAll())  removes all layers from the map. That's not what you want.

Instead, try looping through the `MapView`'s layers and for each layer of type `GraphicsLayer` (but not of type `ArcGISFeatureLayer`), either remove the layer or remove the graphics from the layer. Do something like this:

```
private void somewhereInYourExistingCode() {
    ...
    for (Layer layer : map.getLayers()) {
        clearGraphics(layer);
    }
    ...
}

private void clearGraphics(Layer layer) {
    /**
     * ArcGISFeatureLayer extends GraphicsLayer, but what you're
     * probably looking for is GraphicsLayer objects that are
     * not of type ArcGISFeatureLayer.
     */
    if (layer instanceof GraphicsLayer && !(layer instanceof ArcGISFeatureLayer)) {
        // You can call map.removeLayer(layer), or...
        ((GraphicsLayer) layer).removeAll();
    } else if (layer instanceof GroupLayer) {
        GroupLayer groupLayer = (GroupLayer) layer;
        for (Layer sublayer : groupLayer.getLayers()) {
            // Recursive call
            clearGraphics(sublayer);
        }
    }
}
```